# Why sbt runs dependency resolution every time after clean?

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

SBT runs dependency resolution every time after `clean` even if project dependency management configuration hasn't changed. This is time consuming when running on CI server.

But documentation [says](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Detailed-Topics/Dependency-Management-Flow.html):

> 1. Normally, if no dependency management configuration has changed since the last successful resolution and the retrieved files are still
>      present, sbt does not ask Ivy to perform resolution.

How can I stop sbt from doing dependency resolution every time I build project with `sbt clean publish-local` ?

**Update**

I've discovered that sbt also runs resolution when I enter in interactive mode with `sbt`.

**Update2**

As `@Ezhik` pointed if I can preserve `target/resolution-cache` then sbt will not resolve dependencies after clean.
So I tried to move `resolution-cache` out from target dir:

```
ivyConfiguration <<= (externalResolvers, ivyPaths, offline, checksums, appConfiguration, target, streams) map { (rs, paths, off, check, app, t, s) =>
        val resCacheDir = t / ".." / "resolution-cache"
        new InlineIvyConfiguration(paths, rs, Nil, Nil, off, Option(lock(app)), check, Some(resCacheDir), s.log)
      }
```

Now with this code in `Build.scala` resolution cache is placed in project root and is therefore preserved after `clean`, but resolution is being done anyway. So I assume this approach is wrong or insufficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because of directory `target/resolution-cache` that contains Ivy reports. It is obviously that you remove all `target` content while `clean` operation.

IMHO You must point it in your project to somewhere out from `target` if you want to preserve resolution state.

*Updated.*

vs SBT.0.12.4.RC1

1. Find where `resolution-cache` is used - in IvyConfiguration
2. Inspect where IvyConfiguration located - in project scope

   ```
   > inspect ivy-configuration
   [info] Task: sbt.IvyConfiguration
   [info] Description:
   [info]  General dependency management (Ivy) settings, such as the resolvers and paths to use.
   [info] Provided by:
   [info]  {file:/home/ezh/projects/sbt/}xsbt/*:ivy-configuration
   [info] Dependencies:
   [info]  xsbt/*:offline
   ```
3. Fix it in build.sbt.

   ```
   ivyConfiguration <<= (ivyConfiguration, baseDirectory) map {
     case (c: InlineIvyConfiguration, b) => import c._
       new InlineIvyConfiguration(paths, resolvers, otherResolvers, moduleConfigurations,
        localOnly, lock, checksums, resolutionCacheDir.map(_ => b / "123"), log)
     case (other, _) => other // something unknown
   }
   ```

4 Test... Ups... resolution is still active... Investigate. ->

`target/scala-2.10/cache/default-920e5d/global/update/output` cache contain pointers to `resolution-cache` :)

1. Fix it.

   ```
   cacheDirectory <<= baseDirectory / "234"
   ```

Test. Got it. Resolution is skipped.

Summary changes for required configuration:

```
ivyConfiguration <<= (ivyConfiguration, baseDirectory) map {
  case (c: InlineIvyConfiguration, b) => import c._
    new InlineIvyConfiguration(paths, resolvers, otherResolvers, moduleConfigurations,
     localOnly, lock, checksums, resolutionCacheDir.map(_ => b / "123"), log)
  case (other, _) => other // something unknown
}
cacheDirectory <<= baseDirectory / "234"
```

---

vs SBT.0.13.x

```
@deprecated("Use the cacheDirectory provided by streams.", "0.13.0")
```

https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1208

Comment: With your own hands? SBT is very expressive.  OK special for you :))) And for me as a funny case.

Comment: +1, great answer @Ezhik. Sadly this solution will not work with sbt 0.13, unfortunately. cacheDirectory has been deprecated (and as far as the dependency resolution workaround is concerned, cacheDirectory has been effectively removed). I have yet to find a workable solution on 0.13, frustrating having sbt check for updates on every single clean/compile.

Comment: @virtualeyes: any luck coming up with a working solution for 0.13.x?

Answer (score 6):

Might be that you have SNAPSHOT  dependencies. They are subject to change anytime so must be resolved on every run. You can suppress this with

```
    offline := true
```

Comment: I'm aware of snapshots. It's not the case. Sbt runs resolution for all dependencies available.

Comment: Sorry where should I apply this line of code build.sbt? Could you please provide some context...

Comment: @khebbie run `set offline := true` in your sbt command line (REPL) OR run sbt with `sbt "set offline := true" run`. You could in theory also add this to your build.sbt, but then you would always have to edit your build file to toggle offline mode.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me on 0.13.1.

```
cleanKeepFiles ++= Seq("resolution-cache", "streams").map(target.value / _)
```

Comment: works for me in 0.13.2 , you need to add that line to all subprojects individually

Answer (score 5):

You can prevent `clean` from deleting certain files with this setting:

```
// path should be adapted for newer sbt versions
cleanKeepFiles <+= cacheDirectory / "update"
```