# Speeding up SBT-assembly

Tags: scala, jenkins, sbt, scalatra, sbt-assembly

We have a project where we are building a large number of [Scalatra](http://www.scalatra.org/) [microservices](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) by packaging them using the [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin, then creating Docker images using the [sbt-docker](https://github.com/marcuslonnberg/sbt-docker) plugin. The process is slow due to the number of micro-services because the assembly plugin has to process all the transitive dependencies for each service. However I note most of the micro-services have very similar dependencies. Is there any way to speed this up?

One limitation is we are doing this on Jenkins (CI) server so we are calling `sbt clean` at the start so we are not able to take advantage of any caching?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190755/why-sbt-runs-dependency-resolution-every-time-after-clean Did you try scalatra-sbt's DistPlugin? It creates a directory layout containing the libraries instead of a fat-jar. It may be worth a try if the cause was not the slow dependency resolution process of SBT.

Comment: Oh, it seems not to work for 0.13.x...

Answer (score 6):

You could assemble a common dependency jar that has all the dependencies all your microservices need, which you would only need to build once. Then you could assemble jars for each of the microservices without any of the dependencies.

See "[Splitting your project and deps JARs](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#splitting-your-project-and-deps-jars)".